# What's the fastest way to populate an array with numbers in PHP?

Tags: php, arrays

What's the fastest way to populate an array with the numbers 1-100 in PHP? I want to avoid doing something like this:

```
$numbers = '';

for($var i = 0; i <= 100; $i++) {
    $numbers = $i . ',';
}

$numberArray = $numbers.split(',');
```

It seems long and tedious, is there a faster way?

Comment: Do you want 1 - 100 as you ask in your question, or 0 - 100 as your code and the one by Jason246 suggests?

Comment: I got the general gist of his answer... He could've answered in response to my pseudo code which starts with 0 in the loop. Nice catch though.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The [`range`](http://php.net/range) function:

```
$var = range(0, 100);
```

Answer (score 8):

`range()` would work well, but even with the loop, I'm not sure why you need to compose a string and split it - what's wrong with simply:

```
$numberArray = array();
for ($i = 0; $i < 100; $i++)
  $numberArray[] = $i;
```

Comment: The code was just an example, nonetheless your way is of course much more efficient than mine :)